# Router and modem not working parallely

Tags: home-networking

My modem is 192.168.1.X network and my wireless router is 192.168.2.X network. i am connecting both of them to switch.And then connect to system and set static ip address for my system.Any  one of them is working at that time.How to configure that?

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish with such a bizarre setup? Your "modem" is clearly also a router. So what exactly are you trying to accomplish with two routers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't want two routers in the same LAN. Decide whether you want to use your modem as a router (and your router just as a switch and/or access point) or you want to use your router as a router (and your modem just as a modem) and configure your network appropriately. What you have now makes no sense.

If you decide to use your modem just as a modem:

1. Set your modem to bridging mode.
2. Connect your modem's Ethernet port to the router's Internet/WAN port.
3. Don't use any other ports on your modem. If it has Wifi, don't use it.

If you decide to use your modem as a router and your router just as a switch and/or access point:

1. Disable your router's DHCP server.
2. Don't use your router's Internet/WAN port for any reason.
3. Connect a LAN port on the router to the modem or switch.

Comment: I have wireless router connecting with internet access. in wifi internet are available. how to block internet in wifi